# How to move row after/before first occurence of specific row with known classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS event tied to upArrow :

```js
$('body').on('click', '.UpArrow', function(event) {
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="placeholderRow NameServiceRow">
  <td class="UpArrow"></td>
  <td class="DownArrow"></td>
  <td><input value="2" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="placeholderRow inlineService">
  <td class="UpArrow"></td>
  <td class="DownArrow"></td>
  <td><input value="2" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="placeholderRow inlineService">
  <td class="UpArrow"></td>
  <td class="DownArrow"></td>
  <td><input value="2" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="placeholderRow">
  <td class="UpArrow"></td>
  <td class="DownArrow"></td>
  <td><input value="2" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is move TR above the TR with class name `NameServiceRow`

I already tried a number of solutions but none of them worked for me , if you have any solutions I am all ears.

EDIT :

I may have multiple rows with classname `NameServiceRow` so what I want is to move it above the first occurence of this classname

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. When i click on `UpArrow` it moves the tr above the prev

Comment: I want it move above the TR with classname "NameServiceRow" not just above the perv

Comment: try something like ` row.insertBefore(row.prevAll(".NameServiceRow"));`

Comment: it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are looking for something like this? If you need to move the current tr to the tr with class 'NameServiceRow' occurring just above the clicked, this code may be working.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.UpArrow', function(event) {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if(!row.hasClass('NameServiceRow')){
         var parentDiv = row.prevAll('.NameServiceRow:first');
         row.insertBefore(parentDiv);
         row.addClass("NameServiceRow");
         parentDiv.removeClass("NameServiceRow");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr class="placeholderRow NameServiceRow">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="A 1" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow inlineService">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="A 2" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow inlineService">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="A 3" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="A 4" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow NameServiceRow">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="B 1" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow inlineService">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="B 2" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow inlineService">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="B 3" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="B 4" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow NameServiceRow">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="C 1" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow inlineService">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="C 2" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow inlineService">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="C 3" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="placeholderRow">
   <td class="UpArrow">-</td>
   <td class="DownArrow">+</td>
   <td><input value="C 4" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

you can decide whether to change class using

```
row.addClass("NameServiceRow");
parentDiv.removeClass("NameServiceRow");
```

Comment: I may have a lot of rows with classname " NameServiceRow " so removing it from the first one is may be working on this case where I only have one TR with this classname but if I have many of them it would not work , what do you suggest replacing first with ?

Comment: while clicking 'UpArrow',do you want to move the row to just above tr with class  'NameServiceRow' ?

Comment: @samouray : I've updated the answer. please see to it.

Comment: It worked , but I didn't use the removeclass/removeclass elements because in my case I need those names to remain the same , I accepted your answer , it was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.UpArrow', function(event) {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    row.insertBefore($(".NameServiceRow")[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="placeholderRow NameServiceRow">
  <td class="UpArrow">^</td>
  <td class="DownArrow"></td>
  <td><input value="2" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="placeholderRow inlineService">
  <td class="UpArrow">^</td>
  <td class="DownArrow"></td>
  <td><input value="3" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="placeholderRow NameServiceRow">
  <td class="UpArrow">^</td>
  <td class="DownArrow"></td>
  <td><input value="2" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="placeholderRow inlineService">
  <td class="UpArrow">^</td>
  <td class="DownArrow"></td>
  <td><input value="4" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="placeholderRow">
  <td class="UpArrow">^</td>
  <td class="DownArrow"></td>
  <td><input value="5" class="ref" name="ref2" readonly="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i tried it , the row stays in it's place. , it dosent move

Comment: @samouray It is working for me. What happens if you click on `Run code snippet` and then click the `^` of any row under the first one?

Comment: I already run the code snippet and it's working ,  I tested it directly on my file with no movement of the row,  also I want it to move before the first occurence of this class , maybe I wasn't clear I apologize , I edited my question

Comment: @samouray Alright, I edited my answer to match your new question. It should work now.

Comment: +1 for your answer and comments , I accepted gjijo 's asnwer because it was more like what I was expecting , I appreciate you taking the time to respond Sir